# New mat-grid-list inside Parent mat-grid-list is not working

Tags: angular, grid, angular-material-6

I am trying to put mat-grid-list inside **PARENT** mat-grid-list.

Below is the code -

```
<mat-grid-list cols="12" rowHeight="2:1" gutterSize=2px>

<mat-grid-tile colspan="12" rowspan="1"  [style.background-color]="'brown'">
 LOGO
</mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile colspan="1" rowspan="16"  [style.background-color]="'brown'">
 Navigation
</mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile colspan="8" rowspan="16">
**<app-child-content></app-child-content>** New Component includes mat-grid
</mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile colspan="3" rowspan="16"  [style.background-color]="'brown'">
 Trending
</mat-grid-tile>

</mat-grid-list>
```

**App Child Component's Content** --

```
<mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="1" gutterSize=2px>

<mat-grid-tile colspan="1" rowspan="1"  [style.background-color]="'brown'">
  Child Grid list Not Working
</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it but still lot to learn- provide 100% height and 100% width properties to the child component.

```
<app-child-content class="child-css"></app-child-content>
.child-css{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: thank you, the child should have a width of 100% in order to work.